# When using dynamic="true" on p:tabView, other tabs doesn't open and commandlink in 1st tab is not invoked

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF 2.0 with PrimeFaces 3.0 M3. When I set `dynamic="false"` on `<p:tabView>`, then it works fine. But when I set it to `true`, then only the currently active tab works. Other tabs does not run. In the 1st tab I have a command link in a data table, this is also not working.

Below is my `tabletabview.xhtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <f:view>
            <h:form>
                <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
                <p:tabView cache="false"  dynamic="true" activeIndex=0 >
                    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="ActivityController.onChange"/>
                    <p:tab title="Search Results 1">
                        <p:dataTable var="dataItem" value="#{ActivityController.dataList}">
                            <p:column>
                                <p:panel style="font-size:12px;width:600px">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dataItem.activityname}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <div style="background-color: #DEB887;">
                                        <h:outputText value="Location:" style="color:#FF0000;"></h:outputText>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dataItem.address}" />
                                        <br></br>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="background-color: #DEB887;">
                                        <h:outputText value="Start Date:" style="color:#FF0000;"></h:outputText>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dataItem.startingdate}" />
                                        <br></br>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="background-color: #DEB887;">
                                        <h:outputText value="Start Date:" style="color:#FF0000;"></h:outputText>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dataItem.endingdate}" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="background-color: #DEB887;">
                                        <h:outputText value="Description:" style="color:#FF0000;"></h:outputText>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dataItem.description}" />
                                        <br></br>
                                    </div>
                                    <p:commandLink action="#{ActivityController.editDataItem}">
                                        <div style="display: none">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{dataItem.activityname}" />
                                        </div>
                                        <h:outputText value="more....."></h:outputText>
                                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ActivityController.dataItem}" value="#{dataItem}" />
                                    </p:commandLink>
                                </p:panel>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab title="Search Results 2">
                        <p:panel style="width:600px;height:600px">
                            <p:schedule id="sche" value="#{searchController.eventModel}"
                                editable="true" draggable="false" resizable="false"
                                widgetVar="myschedule">
                                <p:ajax event="eventSelect"
                                    listener="#{searchController.onEventSelect}" update="red"
                                    process="@this" />
                            </p:schedule>
                        </p:panel>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab id="gmap" title="Search Results 3">
                        <ui:include src="/locationpointers.xhtml"></ui:include>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:tabView>
            </h:form>
        </f:view>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is the relevant part of my `ActivityController.java`

```
public List<ActivityRegBean> getDataList() {
    return dataList;
}

public void setDataList(List<ActivityRegBean> dataList){
    this.dataList=dataList;
}

private ActivityRegBean dataItem;
private HtmlInputHidden dataItemId = new HtmlInputHidden() ;


public String editDataItem() throws IOException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    System.out.println(dataItem.activityname);
    dataItemId.setValue(dataItem.activityid);
    System.out.println(dataItem.activityid);
    retfromtable(dataItem.activityname);
    return "edit"; // Navigation case.
}

public void onChange(TabChangeEvent event) { 
    System.out.println("tab id = " + event.getTab().getId());
}
```

The `ActivityRegBean` has a getter and setter.

How can I use `dynamic="true"` on the `<p:tabView>` without problems?

Comment: i have used Primefaces RC1 as well as RC2. but still it does'nt work.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this instead of p:ajax

```
<p:tabView cache="false"  dynamic="true" tabChangeListener="#{ActivityController.onChange}" onTabChangeUpdate="growl">
```

I have noticed that you are using xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui" . It is for primefaces 2.2 and if you are indeed using primefaces 3, then it will complain about no taglibrary exists for that namespace. for PF3 you should be using     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" . may be you should clean your work directory.

Comment: This was introduced in M4. OP is using M3. Even more, using wrong taglib URI would result in completely different results (i.e. components are not rendered at all). This is not the case here.